# Why Laravel form not reaching the URL, redirecting back with empty message

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm developing a website in Laravel 5.8, its login & others forms were working fine earlier but suddenly stopped working. Whenever i'm hitting the form, its not reaching to the URL and redirecting back without any message.

```
https://transformbadminton.com/web/login
```

Please help i'm trying to solve this since 3 hour but still no success.

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more information than that for any of us to have any idea what may be causing it. What do you mean by "redirecting back", for starters? How is your route declared? Does it reach its associated controller/function? etc.

Comment: In Lravel is websiteaddress/login without web prefix